# Why do we care about Echelon form not being unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the context of solving a system of linear equations, I seem to always be able to solve systems by only using the Echelon form of a matrix. Specifically, if it's a 3x3 coefficient matrix, I can always back-substitute.

Is there a reason why echelon form *not* being unique is a particular problem?

Comment: What definition of "echelon form" are you using? For any definition I know, the echelon form *is* unique.

Comment: @Ted You're probably thinking of the "reduced row-echelon form". [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) explains the distinction

Comment: The row echelon form is also unique, if the pivot is required to be a 1. (I've never encountered a text which didn't require that.)

Comment: @Ted It is not because the entries above the pivot are not necessarily zero

Comment: @Ted As an example, the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&2\\0&1&3}, \quad \pmatrix{1 & 0&-1\\0&1&3}
$$
are two echelon forms for the same linear system

Comment: Sorry yeah you're right, I was thinking RREF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason that the uniqueness of reduced row-echelon form is convenient is that it allows you to conclusively check for an equivalence of linear system. For instance, $Ax = 0$ and $Bx = 0$ will have the same solutions if **and only if** $A$ and $B$ have the same reduced row-echelon form. By contrast, $A$ and $B$ could have distinct row-echelon forms without these two systems being equivalent.

Another important (and equivalent) point: $A$ and $B$ will have the same row-spaces if and only if their reduced row-echelon form is the same.

As for the sentiment "I can always just back substitute", you should know that the math you're doing when back-substituting is exactly the same math that you would need to put the system into reduced row-echelon form. For example, consider the augmented matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
3 & 4 & 23\\0 & 1 & 5
\end{array}\right].
$$
Of course, you could convert this back into a system of equations and back substitute:
$$
3x + 4y = 23\\
y = 5  \\
\implies 3x + 4(5) = 23\\
\implies 3x = 23 - 4(5)\\
\implies 3x = 3\\
\implies x = 1.
$$
On the other hand, you end up doing the exact same computations ($23 - 4(5) = 3$ and $3/3 = 1$) when you just use row operations; you just save yourself the trouble of writing variable names
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
3 & 4 & 23\\0 & 1 & 5
\end{array}\right] \to \\
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
3 & 4 - 4(1) & 23 - 4(5)\\0 & 1 & 5
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
3 & 0 & 3\\0 & 1 & 5
\end{array}\right] \to \\
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
3/3 & 0 & 3/3\\0 & 1 & 5
\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 5
\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: So echelon form is essentially just a pit stop along the way to getting the RREF? My textbook makes the "important" distinction that echelon form is NOT unique, but beyond determining the equivalence of separate linear systems, I can't figure out why we would care about it not being unique since it doesn't impact our solution at all. Naively, it seems that putting the matrix into RREF is simply more visually convenient and introduces more possibilities for algebraic mistakes whereas back-substituting is just plug-and-play.

Comment: @TheMathPotato I would argue that it is indeed just a pit stop on the way to RREF, but you can get a lot of important information about the system of equations without going past that point. Also, determining the equivalence of linear systems is pretty important as it turns out. Both REF -> RREF and back-substituting are frameworks for the exact same arithmetic steps; both are fine, but the augmented matrix formalism saves you some writing once you're used to it.

Comment: Could you give an example where determining the equivalence of linear systems is important, beyond a typical math exercise? 

Also, would it be correct to say that two linear systems are equivalent if they have the exact same solution set? For instance, if two lines intersect at the point (1, 2) and another two completely different lines intersect at (1, 2), do we say those linear systems are equivalent?

Comment: @TheMathPotato I'd say the real power behind the RREF (in the context of introductory linear algebra anyway) is that you can essentially "read off" the solution to the corresponding system of equations, whereas REF requires additional work.

Comment: @TheMathPotato In this context, yes that's what I mean by an equivalence of two systems

Comment: Ben, you might enjoy this recent question, it appears you  have not commented on it : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840379/gauss-jordan-elimination-gives-inconsistent-matrix-for-a-consistent-system  Amazing the OP keeps complaining about echelon form not working properly, finally it turned out he was using his own, incorrect, program

Comment: @Will I appreciate the update!